# Posting null values via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Using the jQuery `$.post` function, if you send a `null` value, it arrives at the server side as `"null"`. Example:

Javascript:

```
$.post('test.php', { foo : null });
```

PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST['foo']); // string(4) "null"
```

I understand why this is so, but was wondering the best way to work around the limitation? Should you:

1. Loop through all the variables in JS before you send them and replace with an empty string?
2. Interpret `"null"` as `null` on the server side?
3. Don't send the variable at all?
4. Something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would encode it into JSON.

E.g.:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'test.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify({foo : null}),
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

You can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the server, and the types will be preserved:

```
$msg = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
var_export($msg->foo); // NULL
```

Comment: For those browsers that don't have a native JSON object you can use [http://www.json.org/json2.js]

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem that I have solved more simply, maybe for you it 'll be too.
In your php file you can do that

`if ($_POST[var] == 'null'){    $_POST[var] = NULL; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the javascript object to JSON with:

```
$.post('test.php', JSON.stringify({ foo : null }));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This would not be a good performance idea, especially if large sets of variables are involved.
2. Possibly. This could be done by looking for all expected values, and ignoring anything else also. directly translating `"null" -> null` could be dangerous if taking in user input.
3. This would result in a variable being not set. it would be possible to use !isset() on that variable then. This would be my choice.

If you didn't want to have convert between JSON, I would use option 3 and simply not send any variables that are null, then use `if (!isset($_POST['my-var']))`

Answer (score -1):

This is a weird fix to get `Dates` to post correctly in `C# MVC`:

```
$.post(url, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ ListOfObjWithDates: listOfObjWithDates })), ...
```